# MySQL calculate moving average of N rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the moving average **of** N rows, **for** all rows in a single query. In the example case, I am attempting to calculate the moving average of 50 rows.

```
SELECT 
    h1.date, 
    h1.security_id, 
    (   SELECT 
            AVG(last50.close)
        FROM (
            SELECT h.close
            FROM history as h
            WHERE h.date <= h1.date AND h.security_id = h1.security_id
            ORDER BY h.date DESC
            LIMIT 50
        ) as last50
    ) as avg50
FROM history as h1
```

However, MySQL gives me an error when running this query:

`Unknown column 'h1.date' in 'where clause'`

I'm trying this method because the other solutions listed don't really seem to work for my use case. There are solutions for a moving average of N *days*, but since all dates are not accounted for in my data set, I need the average of N *rows*.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059693/how-to-calculated-multiple-moving-average-in-mysql), shown below, doesn't work because `AVG` (also `SUM` and `COUNT`)  doesn't account for `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
  t1.data_date
  ( SELECT SUM(t2.price) / COUNT(t2.price)
    FROM t as t2
    WHERE t2.data_date <= t1.data_date
    ORDER BY t2.data_date DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) AS 'five_row_moving_average_price'
FROM t AS t1
ORDER BY t1.data_date;
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121887/how-to-calculate-a-moving-average-in-mysql-in-a-correlated-subquery) looks promising, but is somewhat indecipherable to me.

Any suggestions? [Here's an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae912) to play around in.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I created an SQLFiddle to experiment in

Comment: Fantastic. You're halfway there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**plan**

> - self join history on last 50 days
> - take average grouping by date and security id ( of current )

**query**

```
select curr.date, curr.security_id, avg(prev.close)
from history curr
inner join history prev 
on prev.`date` between date_sub(curr.`date`, interval 49 day) and curr.`date`
and curr.security_id = prev.security_id
group by 1, 2
order by 2, 1
;
```

**output**

```
+---------------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|           date            | security_id |  avg(prev.close)   |
+---------------------------+-------------+--------------------+
| January, 04 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.770000457763672 |
| January, 05 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.800000190734863 |
| January, 06 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.673333485921225 |
| January, 07 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.59250020980835  |
| January, 08 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.432000160217285 |
| January, 11 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.40166680018107  |
| January, 12 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.344285828726631 |
| January, 13 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.297500133514404 |
| January, 14 2016 00:00:00 | 1           | 10.2877779006958   |
| January, 04 2016 00:00:00 | 2           | 56.15999984741211  |
| January, 05 2016 00:00:00 | 2           | 56.18499946594238  |
| ..                        | ..          | ..                 |
+---------------------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/128c0e/6)

**reference**

- [sql rolling averages](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/rolling-average.html)

---

**modified to use last 50 rows**

```
select
rnk_curr.`date`, rnk_curr.security_id, avg(rnk_prev50.close)
from
(
select `date`, security_id,
@row_num := if(@lag = security_id, @row_num + 1,
               if(@lag := security_id, 1, 1)) as row_num
from history 
cross join ( select @row_num := 1, @lag := null ) params
order by security_id, `date`
) rnk_curr
inner join
(
select date, security_id, close,
@row_num := if(@lag = security_id, @row_num + 1,
               if(@lag := security_id, 1, 1)) as row_num
from history 
cross join ( select @row_num := 1, @lag := null ) params
order by security_id, `date`
) rnk_prev50
on  rnk_curr.security_id = rnk_prev50.security_id
and rnk_prev50.row_num between rnk_curr.row_num - 49 and rnk_curr.row_num
group by 1,2
order by 2,1
;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/128c0e/7)

**note**

the if function is to force the correct order of evaluation of variables.

Comment: @Strawberry fixed to use intervals

Comment: Good, but note that the last 50 days may not correspond to the last 50 rows

Comment: true, this depends on what the OP really wants

Comment: Right, it must be the last 50 *rows*, not dates

Comment: added also query to use last 50 rows ( not dates )

Comment: This seems to work (although it should be `row_num - 49` not `50`). This is definitely harder than it should be

Comment: in MySQL it certainly is harder than it should be (window functions make this far easier sadly missing in MySQL so far)

Comment: adjusted to 49. true without window functions, have to play with variables.

Answer (score 2):

In mysql 8 [window function frame](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) can be used to obtain the averages.

```
SELECT date, security_id, AVG(close) OVER (PARTITION BY security_id ORDER BY date ROWS 49 PRECEDING) as ma
FROM history
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This calculates the average of the current row and 49 preceding rows.